# Pass commands when switching to root

Tags: command-line, sudo

I am switching to root user using `sudo -i` , but is it possible to pass a command for execution in the same line itself ?
Ex: `sudo -i -c "mkdir qq"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
$ sudo -i /bin/bash -c 'mkdir qq && bash'

# pwd
/root

# ls -d qq
qq
```

first you pass `/bin/bash` as your shell, `mkdir qq` as the command you want to be run and `&& bash` to get a shell with root access.

Comment: I guess you don't even need the `-i`, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

`sudo` runs commands. Just do:

```
sudo -i mkdir qq
```

You don't need a special option like with `su`.

Comment: Yes, I'm almost sure this is what the OP was looking for, because they passed the `-c` flag, which when passed to `su` or most shells causes a single command to be run. What they didn't know is that running a single command is the common use of `sudo`, requiring no special flag. Depending on what they're doing, though, they may not need `-i` either.

Answer (score 2):

As [muru says](https://askubuntu.com/a/952200/22949), the typical use of `sudo` is to run just one command. You don't need to pass the `-c` flag like you would with most shells or the `su` command.

However, depending on what you intend the result to be of running `mkdir qq`, you may want to omit the `-i` flag as well. Whether you run `sudo -i` without a command argument to start a shell or with a command argument (`sudo -i command...`) to run a single command, `sudo -i` simulates the environment you would get *if you were to log in as the target user*. When no target user is specified, that user is `root`, whose home directory is `/root`. Logging in as a user places you in their home directory, so `sudo -i` does that, too, though just for the shell being launched or the single command being run.

Thus running `sudo -i mkdir qq` actually runs `mkdir qq` as root from `/root`. Since `qq` is a [relative path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Absolute_and_relative_paths), the directory that command creates is actually `/root/qq`, i.e., a directory called `qq` inside the `/root` directory. If that's what you want, great! But if what you want is actually to create a directory called `qq` wherever you are right now, then  you should do one of these things instead:

- To create a directory there is usually no reason you need `root`'s full login environment. So you can just drop the `-i` flag and run `sudo mkdir qq`.
- In the quite unlikely event you needed `root`'s login environment to create a directory--I cannot think of a reason you would--then you can use the full path to the directory. Although I doubt you'll need that in this case, it's good to know that you use a full path in a command you run with `sudo -i` to make sure you're referring to the correct file or directory. For example, if your goal were to create `qq`  in `/opt`, you could run `sudo -i mkdir /opt/qq`. Again, though, for `mkdir` this shouldn't be necessary, just drop the `-i`.
- If you don't need to run a command as `root` or any other alternate user, don't. To create a new directory somewhere your user already has write access, you're better off just running `mkdir qq` without `sudo`. In particular, if this `qq` directory is where you are going to install the instant messaging program QQ for use only by you, and not other users on the system, and you are creating it inside your home directory, then it's best not to use `sudo` when you install or run the program. (I'm not assuming this is for QQ. That's just an example.)